# How to check what is the soap meesage passed to the server on click of a button? Fiddler?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, debugging, wsdl, fiddler

I want to capture the SOAP request and actual response from the WebService.

Scenario : On click of a button in asp.net application I call a web service. The Web Service returns an exception : `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Access is denied.     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)     at WebRefProject.HRWS.TeamMemberData201012Service.getTeamMemberProfilesByFullName(GetTeamMemberProfilesByFullNameRequest_Type getTeamMemberProfilesByFullName1) in C:\Project\FinalPAT\WebCode\1PSV\WebRefProject\Web References\HRWS\Reference.cs:line 138     at UIPSAT.GetUserDetails.GetUserDetailsbyFullName(String searchValue) in C:\Project\FinalPAT\WebCode\1PSV\UI\GetUserDetails.cs:line 209`

Explanation:

1. I have a asp.net application which calls a web service to search for employee details.
2. The WS requires certificates and we attach it along the request.
3. The service is working good on local with local certificate.
4. It isnt working on Dev server and is giving the above exception.
5. A sample application runs good on Dev with the Dev certificate.
6. How do I know what SOAP is sent to the web service?
7. Also I could not add the reference of the web service directly to the solution as it was protected and Visual Studio IDE could not add it.
8. However the WSDL file was not protected. It was successfully added and the URL of the Web Service was changed based on the appropriate server environments.

How do check the SOAP Request and Response?

Comment: Is the web service local or remote? Fiddler should be able to do either, but configuration is different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: The webservice is hosted on a different server. Remote. I cannot see the soap request even when I check using fiddler.

Comment: Do you have a filter set in Fiddler? The request is coming from the local machine that is also running Fiddler?

Comment: Let me try to explain : 1)I have a asp.net application which calls a web service to search for employee details. 2)The WS requires certificates and we attach it along the request. 3)The service is working good on local with local certificate. 4) It isnt working on Dev server and is giving the above exception. 5)A sample application runs good on Dev with the Dev certificate. 6)How do I know what SOAP is sent to the web service? 7)Also I could not add the reference of the web service directly to the solution as it was protected and Visual Studio IDE could not add it.

Comment: 8)However the WSDL file was not protected. It was successfully added and the URL of the Web Service was changed based on the appropriate server environments.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple problems going on here. Fiddler should be able to inspect traffic from your local machine to the server just fine. If you're testing on "localhost", you will have to add a dot after "localhost" to make it "localhost." in order for Fiddler to pickup the traffic.

Comment: Okay. But works good on the localhost with local certificates. Problem is running on the Dev Servers. Thanks for your inputs. Have a great weekend ahead.

Comment: But is Fiddler running on the machine that is initiating the request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF Diagnostic message logging facilities.  Just config it on your client, the soap messages will be logged. For instance:

```
<diagnostics>     
   <messageLogging              
    logEntireMessage="true"              
    logMalformedMessages="true"             
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"     
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"             
    maxMessagesToLog="1000"             
    maxSizeOfMessageToLog="5000"/>       
</diagnostics>
```

Comment: This is a Visual Studio 2005 ASP.Net application.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure soapUI (http://www.soapui.org/) to act as a logging proxy between your web service client and server. Configure your client to connect to a soapUI proxy instance running on the client host. Configure the soapUI instance to then forward to the service on the remote server.

Comment: Yeah. Could get the log file created using the diagnostics logging. Used the following :  
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
<source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
<listeners>
<add name="System.Net"/>
</listeners>
</source>
<source name="System.Net.Sockets">
<listeners>
<add name="System.Net"/>
</listeners>
</source>
<source name="System.Net.Cache">
<listeners>
<add name="System.Net"/>
</listeners>
</source>
</sources>
<switches>
<add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
<add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>

Comment: <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
</switches>
<sharedListeners>
<add name="System.Net"
type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
initializeData="C:\Projects\1PSV\WebCode\1PSV\UI\bin\trace.log"
/>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the trace file to a location. Add the following to the web.Config file :